# Javascript function get some extra character when insert in inner html of script tag

Tags: javascript, c#

In my app user writes some js code and i insert these code in the script tag and add them in the head tag of html.It was all working fine but when I use for loop in the js function it is getting some extra character after inserting in script tag inner HTML.
User-written function:

```
var el=element1.get();
var vectors=el.shapes;
var vectorCollection=[];
var correctVectors=[[2,3]];
var dotProducts=[];
for(var i=0;i<vectors.length;i++){
if(vectors[i].type<=5)
vectorCollection.push([vectors[i].startX,vectors[i].startY]); 
}
for(var i=0;i<correctVectors.length;i++){
for(var j=0;j<vectorCollection.length;j++){
dotProducts.push(math.dot(correctVectors[i],vectorCollection[j]));
}
} 
}
```

The insert function which user js code as src and insert in inner HTML of script tag:

```
public static void InsertScriptTag(HtmlDocument doc, string id, string src)
    {
        HtmlNode head = GetHead(doc);

        HtmlNode element = doc.CreateElement("script");
        element.SetAttributeValue("id", "autogeneratedcode");
        element.SetAttributeValue("type", "text/javascript");
        element.InnerHtml = src;

        head.AppendChild(element);
    }
```

I have debugged after passing src code to inner HTML it becomes like this:

[image]